# Automatic word spacing to fit line CSS

Tags: html, css, line, word-wrap, line-breaks

How can i make the word spacing automatically expand in order to fit the containers width?

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CKCi.png)

```html
<p class="autoWrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente consectetur vero laboriosam cum quisquam aliquam molestiae minima, ratione a rem, mollitia neque est velit, rerum voluptas tenetur voluptate recusandae modi? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, unde corrupti cum doloribus dolorem repudiandae consequatur quaerat qui soluta dignissimos fuga nulla aspernatur vero nesciunt enim earum sunt repellendus itaque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet earum 
Natus laboriosam earum harum molestiae quaerat doloremque! Error quas asperiores</p>
```

```css
.autoWrap {
  max-width: 500px;
  /* magic word wrap property here */
}
```

Comment: Just a note on accessibility: changing word spacing creates "rivers of white space" that can reduce readability for some people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `text-align: justify;`
You can read more about here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Working example below

```css
.autoWrap {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<p class="autoWrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente consectetur vero laboriosam cum quisquam aliquam molestiae minima, ratione a rem, mollitia neque est velit, rerum voluptas tenetur voluptate recusandae modi? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, unde corrupti cum doloribus dolorem repudiandae consequatur quaerat qui soluta dignissimos fuga nulla aspernatur vero nesciunt enim earum sunt repellendus itaque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet earum 
Natus laboriosam earum harum molestiae quaerat doloremque! Error quas asperiores</p>
```